# Rails error resource_name - devise help routing and rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to render the login view for the Devise gem but I get an error, below is the code I currently have:

This is my `views/users/shared/_links.html.erb`:

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations' %>
  <%= link_to "Didn't receive confirmation instructions?", new_confirmation_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.lockable? && resource_class.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email) && controller_name != 'unlocks' %>
  <%= link_to "Didn't receive unlock instructions?", new_unlock_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>

<%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %><br />
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

And my `config/routes.rb`:

```
Densidste::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'user/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_current_user

  match 'signup' => 'devise/users#new', :as => :signup

  match 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :logout

  devise_for :users do
    get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  resources :sessions

  resources :users

  devise_for :users

  resources :aktivs

  resources :taggingposts

  resources :tags

  resources :kommentares

  resources :posts

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  root :to => "public#index"
end
```

And in my application layout:

```
<%= render("users/shared/links") %>
```

I get the following error in the `_links.html.erb` partial:

```
NameError in Public#index

Showing C:/Rails/Densidste/app/views/users/shared/_links.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `resource_name' for #<#<Class:0x5db76c0>:0x5db6538>

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
2:   <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
3: <% end -%>
4: 
5: <%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/public/index.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Rails/Densidste
```

Finally, in my application controller I have the following:

```
before_filter :resource_name
  def resource_name
    if user_signed_in?
      current_user.name
    else
      :user
    end
  end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`resource_name` is defined in the Devise generated controllers. I don't think you can include those shared links in the application layout, I think they are intended for use on the devise forms (registration,sessions,passwords,confirmations,etc), which are rendered by devise controllers.

If you want to have little login/out snippets in every page, you might want to consider writing those links yourself. For instance, if your object that you're using devise for is `user`, you could write this:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(:user) %><br />
```

the `resource_name` is just the Devise abstraction for the resource you're using. I expect that if you're making this link, you know *which* of your authenticated objects you want to login as, so you can specify it explicitly. You could aslo run `rake routes | grep sessions` and see what the name of the path is and use that directly. For example:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %><br />
```

Comment: I have updated my question how do I create an before_filter :resource_name?

Comment: I believe `resource_name` is generally the underscore version of the class name. You could try `current_user.class.name.underscore`. This should give `user` for an object of type `User` or `fancy_user` for an object of class FancyUser.

Comment: There are some helpful comments about these "resource-specific" helper methods in [devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb)

Comment: thank this works. I replaced *new_registration_path(resource_name)* with *new_user_registration_path* it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `routes.rb` file you are defining a resource called `sessions`, devise also has a resource with the same name.

The solution is simple, just remove the `resources :sessions` from the routes file and everything should work.

The reason this happens is because rails creates route helpers for all resources. So it creates a route helper called new_session_path(format). But devise also creates a helper method called `new_session_path(resource_name)`. The devise version returns a path `new_<resouce_name>_session_path`. In other words, the helpers generated by the routes file override the ones in devise.

Note that this can also happen if you do something like:

```
devise_scope :user do 
  get 'login', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_session
  get 'logout', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_session
end
```

In that case, the solution is to replace `new_session` and `destroy_session` with `login` and `logout` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this error my replacing your app/views/devise/confirmation/new.html file with

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/3684/files

with the file app/views/devise/confirmation/new.html in above link
you can find this file from above link and replace your file with it beacuse there are some changes made in recent version so visit above link and find app/views/devise/confirmation/new.html file from above link and replace it with your project file app/views/devise/confirmation/new.html file

Comment: Should post the code and not a link. Answers shouldn't rely on an external source.