# Devise error "undefined local variable or method `resource_class' "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the same problem as here [undefined local variable or method `resource_class' in devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710717/undefined-local-variable-or-method-resource-class-in-devise/37472011#37472011) . The issue is that the code was already set like the answers. Is it a route problem ? Should I look elsewhere?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_locale
  before_action :set_instances
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :mixpanel

  def set_locale
   I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def redirect_to_back
   begin
    redirect_to :back
    rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError => e
    redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def set_instances
    @new_event ||= Event.new(title: ".......", capacity: 50, start_date: Time.zone.now, start_time: Time.zone.now, end_time: Time.zone.now)
    @featured_quizz ||= Questionnaire.where('featured IS TRUE')
  end

   helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping

  protected


  def resource_name
   :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:name, :firstname, :lastname, :phone]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:name, :firstname, :lastname, :image, :phone]
  end

end
```

=> _links.html.slim

```
.row.text-center
.col-md-10.col-md-offset-1

  - if devise_mapping.omniauthable?
    - resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider|
      = link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class:"btn btn-fb btn-block callout callout-fb"
        span.fa.fa-facebook-official<>
        span Connectez vous avec #{provider.to_s.titleize}
```

> undefined method `users_path' for #<#:0x007ff25695fce0>

Is it a syntax error in front ?

```
  li = link_to "Votre Compte", resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), remote: true, data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#login-modal" }
```

or is it the block in my routes.rb =>

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
  :registrations => "registrations",
  :sessions => "sessions",
  :confirmations => "confirmations", 
  :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
devise_for :admins
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: type "bundle exec rake routes" in your console and post the output above.

Comment: I tried and it's fuge. Over 36000 caracters. Can't ad it even in a new question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is devise related : the [Devise Readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes) makes no mention of creating routes for the model used in `devise_for`

the `users_path` helper method is enabled from `config/routes.rb` with the line :

```
get '/users', to: 'users#index', as: :users
```

or shortly, since you will probably need more routes :

```
resources :users, only: [:index] # you can skip the :only parameter if you need all restful routes.
```

Check [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information.

Comment: resources :users, to: 'users#index', as: :users & resources :users, only: [:index] ==> gives me "undefined local variable or method `resource_class' for #<#<Class:0x007fcaf11c5160>:0x007fcaf06e76d0>"  with the block in _links.html.slim above

Comment: It seems that the problem is in resource_class. Help please, Has been three days I'm trying :(

Comment: Ok, just add only one of the lines (rails way is `resources :users`). Gonna try to look into it further, but i guess you'll have to use something like `link_to :user`.

Comment: I tried all what passed in my small head. Still got the error "undefined local variable or method `resource_class'" on the block in _links.html.slim above

Comment: from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview : have you tried `link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider) do ...` ?

Comment: also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955224/rails-error-resource-name-devise-help-routing-and-rendering